# Is it possible to scrape all google scholar results on a particular topic and is it legal?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, google-scholar

I have some Rexperience, but not with website coding, and think I was not able to select the correct CSS nodes to parse (I believe).

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(selectr)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)

url <-'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C38&q=apex+predator+conservation&btnG=&oq=apex+predator+c'
webpage <- read_html(url)

title_html <- html_nodes(webpage, 'a#rh06x-YUUvEJ')
title <- html_text(title_html)
head(title)
```

Ultimately, if I could scrape and divide all scholar results into a csv file with headers like 'Title', 'Author', 'Year', 'Journal', that would be great. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: **Possible**? Yes. **Legal**? Tricky question: yes at best, gray area at worse (depends on the jurisdiction). **Allowed**? Probably not, the scrapers do not want you to scrap them.

Comment: this is definitely disallowed by GS's terms of service: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34970/how-to-get-permission-from-google-to-use-google-scholar-data-if-needed : "[don't] try to access [our services] using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide."

Comment: @AakashUpraity I wonder if you worked out how to scrape `Journal`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concerning your code, you almost had it - you did not select the proper element. I believe you selected by `id` where I found `html_nodes` works best when selecting by `class`. The classes you are looking for are `gs_rt` and `gs_a`.

With `regex`you can then process the data to the desired format by extracting authors and years.

```
url_name <- 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C38&q=apex+predator+conservation&btnG=&oq=apex+predator+c'
wp <- xml2::read_html(url_name)
# Extract raw data
titles <- rvest::html_text(rvest::html_nodes(wp, '.gs_rt'))
authors_years <- rvest::html_text(rvest::html_nodes(wp, '.gs_a'))
# Process data
authors <- gsub('^(.*?)\\W+-\\W+.*', '\\1', authors_years, perl = TRUE)
years <- gsub('^.*(\\d{4}).*', '\\1', authors_years, perl = TRUE)
# Make data frame
df <- data.frame(titles = titles, authors = authors, years = years, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: apart from scraping the titles, authors and years, I wonder if there's a way to scrape the journals that the papers are published in?